# IE New Element with Style?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have this stylesheet:

```
.pixel{
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

And this javascript:

```
function drawpixel(x,y){
    el = document.createElement('div');
    el.setAttribute('class','pixel');
    el.style.left = x;
    el.style.top = y;
    /*  IE needs this for some reason?
    el.style.position = "absolute";
    el.style.backgroundColor = "#FFCC00";
    el.style.width = "2px";
    el.style.height = "2px";
    */
    el.style.fontSize = "0px";
    el.style.lineHeight = "0px";
    document.body.appendChild(el);
}

function mover(event){
    element = document.getElementById("coords");
    element.innerHTML = event.clientX + " " + event.clientY;
    drawpixel(event.clientX, event.clientY);
}
```

Which allows me to "draw" with divs. But IE requires those 4 commented lines - it won't read the class information for some reason?

Is there any easier way to "fix" it for IE, or do I pretty much just have to have those 4 lines?

thanks

Comment: How many pixels do you intend to draw because that is going to perform really, really badly.

Comment: It's interesting that I can draw /massive/ amounts in Chrome with a fair amount of lag, but only drawing a relative few pixels in IE results in serious lag/crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `el.className = "pixel";`

Just something else I noticed.  I know the question states that this is for IE but it looks like you are using your `mover(event)` in an event handler.  If you are using Firefox and other browsers you may want to consider coding the mover function like this:

```
function mover(evt){  
    evt = evt || event;                                                           
    element = document.getElementById("coords");                                 
    element.innerHTML = evt .clientX + " " + evt .clientY;                     
    drawpixel(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);                                     
}
```

Comment: Well that's good to know. I had tried the el.className before but I guess something else wasn't working. For the event thing, the tutorials I've read actually used event that way. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Your `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` should be `evt.clientX` and `evt.clientY`.

Answer (score 4):

In IE ([due to this bug](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-242-setattribute-doesnt-always-work.html)) you need to change this:

```
el.setAttribute('class','pixel');
```

to

```
el.setAttribute('className','pixel');
```

IE's implementation of `setAttribute()` is **woefully broken** before IE8 (running in *IE8 standards mode*)

Comment: You should never try to set a class name using `setAttribute()`. Just use `el.className` instead.

Comment: using `setAttribute()` is absolutely fine, as long as you use `className`.  I'm not going to avoid using standard ECMAScript DOM manipulation methods just because old legacy versions of IE couldn't implement the specs correctly (end rant)

Comment: IE's implementation of *everything* is woefully broken, I've come to discover. el.className works back to IE 5, though, which *should* be the furthest back I'll have to support. This is all intranet sites, and right now I'm just learning the web front-end stuff, and learning new and exciting reasons to hate Internet Explorer.

Comment: `className` goes back to IE 4. Also, `className` works uniformly across all the major scriptable browsers since IE 4, it's not going away so standard or no standard, it is the best thing to use.

Comment: I regretfully currently support IE6 on existing projects - but new projects do not support IE6 at all.  As for IE5.5, IE5, and IE4 - they are beyond dead browsers - I refuse to support them.

Comment: scunliffe: That's fine, I'm not suggesting you should support IE 4, 5 or 5.5. I'd be very surprised if any specification says anything to suggest `el.setAttribute('className','pixel');` should mean setting the `class` attribute, whereas the `className` property does appear in the W3C DOM 2 HTML spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-95362176

Comment: I agree, both methods work and either is fine. I think I got on the defensive after @Marcel's comment of *"You should never try to set a class name using setAttribute()"* which rubbed me the wrong way.  In reality due to IE's lack of standards I'd actually advocate using jQuery or similar to abstract away IE's mountain of bugs. ;-)